# IShellFolder with service application

Tags: delphi

I am using shellobj unit to list network shares with subfolders using IShellFolder interface but it doens't work in windows service application. Can some one advise a way to solve that problem

thanks

Comment: You could try changing your code. I can't be more specific as you did not show your code. Please provide a [mcve].

Comment: Probably the code works fine but the volumes aren't mapped in the server context.

Comment: If the shares are mapped to drive letters, for instance, those mappings are per-user, so the service needs to run as, or impersonate, a particular user to gain access to that user's mappings.

Answer (score 1):

As David mentioned you have to make sure your service runs in the correct context. See [this post here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/desktop/AD/about-service-logon-accounts).

> The logon account determines the security identity of the service at
>   run time, that is, the service's primary security context. The
>   security context determines the service's ability to access local and
>   network resources. For example, a service running in the security
>   context of a local user account cannot access network resources.